# Is a new form automatically started in the same process as the calling form?

Tags: c#, winforms, process

When initialising and then opening a new form from my main form as following,

```
Form testForm = new Form();
testForm.ShowDialog();
```

is it then started in the main form's process? Or does it depend on the method I'm using to show the form?

And if so, how can I start my new form in a new, separated process?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841(v=vs.85).aspx and http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-process-and-thread

Comment: Just explain what problem you're trying to solve, because "start a form in a new process" is unclear.

Comment: It will start in the same thread in the same process. Your application has a single UI thread. If you need to do something in another thread, create another thread or use async/await pattern and interact with the main UI thread when needed.

Comment: What do you mean by process ? Maybe you mean threads ? Can you explain your problem more detailed please

Comment: Let's try to turn things around. Does `ShowDialog()` seem to do what you need it to do? If not, please describe *what's not working the way you want it to*. Be *specific*. ("It should run in another process" isn't the right answer here - that's a *solution* that you've jumped into making without documenting the *problem*)

Answer (score 0):

The main form is run in the main thread, to run a function in WinForm in a another thread, use the `Control.BeginInvoke` method.